# Tokenizing a string in C++

Tags: c++, tokenize

**Description:** Building basic code in C++ for tokenizing string(whitespaces included).

**The main idea:** To call a local function that counts all the whitespaces in a string using their null value for the beginning.

**The problem:** Early termination before reaching the second token.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char *next_token = NULL;

int count_spaces(const char *p);

char *p;

int main() {
    char s[81];

    cout << "Input a string : ";
    cin.getline(s, 81);

    p = strtok_s(s, ", ", &next_token);

    while (p != nullptr) {
        cout << p << endl;
        p = strtok_s(nullptr, ", ", &next_token);
    }

    count_spaces(p);

    cout << count_spaces(p);

    return 0;
}

int count_spaces(const char *p) {
    int number = 0, len;
    if (p == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (*p) {
        if (*p == '1')
            len = 0;
        else if (++len == 1)
            number++;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `count_spaces` doesn't count spaces...and doesn't return any interesting value. Read carefully what the compiler says first... Your code is seriously broken.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. Anyhow, verify your assumption about how to determine whether something is whitespace.

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't compile with these errors. You never succeeded to create this program.

Comment: Im using MVStudio 17, it runs great there and everything is ok till it calls the local function which outputs zero. How can i manipulate the local function so it will count all the non chars in string ?

Comment: Did you read and understand the warnings the compiles spits out?

Comment: What output do you expect? Did you consider investing half an hours to learn the basics of the Visual Studio debugger which is really very easy to use.

Comment: breaks how? From that code I can't see how it'd output anything but 0

Comment: @MichaelWalz finally! thanks for your time invested in my issue. Yes, i read the comments of the compiler : "not all control paths return a value" for line 45 of the code. Which indeed makes sense and this was the point which i understood that i have a problem in the local function. Im learning from a book and this task was a week ago, spent lots of hours on configuring the solution.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and no i didnt spent hours on learning the basics of the VS debugger. Its my bad.

Comment: @Mabadai spent some time learning the debugger, it's easy and will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tokenizing part of your program works. But when you call `count_spaces(p)`, `p` is always `NULL` (or `nullptr` which is pretty much the same).

Maybe you want this (I left out the tokenizing part):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int count_spaces(const char *p);

int main() {
  char s[81];
  cout << "Input a string : ";
  cin.getline(s, sizeof s);      // using sizeof s is better than repeating "81"

  cout << "Number of spaces in string: " << count_spaces(s) << endl;
  return 0;
}

int count_spaces(const char *p) {
  if (p == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  int nbofspaces = 0;

  while (*p) {
    if (*p == ' ') { 
      nbofspaces++;
    }
    p++;
  }

  return nbofspaces;
}
```

Disclaimer:  this is poor C++ code. It is rather what you would do in C, but this code sticks as closely as possible to the OP's original code.

Comment: I'm kinda liking it `:)` Looks like what a true efficient C-programmer would do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's of course not good C++ code, it just sticks to the OP's  original code.

Comment: Ah, the only thing it is missing is some whacky Template to make it type agnostic for `string` or `cstring`. I don't think there is a C++ way of counting `spaces` unless you only take a `string` and use a `auto` range-based loop (but it still just boils down to counting spaces)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Michael thank you very much for your comment/solution this solved my problem. I got a tiny more question, in the code you posted her, in line 26 :    if (*p == ' ') {  , how the compiler recognizes the space in the apostrophes? when i changed the value to 0 the code didnt work approprietly. What happens behind the compiler ?

Comment: @Mabadai the compiler recognizes the space between the apostrophes because the _is_  a space between the apostrophes, just like it would recognize an A between apostrophes (`'A'`). A letter between apostrophes is equivalent to the ASCII code of the letter, e.g. writing `'A'` is the same as writing `65`.

Comment: Ok, noted that in my mind. Once again, thank you for solving my issue.